# repeating 24 hours counter in swiftUI

Tags: timer

Im trying to teach myself some swift to eventually build an app. Im trying to build a repeating 24 hours timer with the notation "24:00:00". Every time the timer expires there should be some changes in the view, like the text label. Here is some code for the timer i´ve builded yet. I hope someone could help me with my problem.

```
struct timer: View {
@State var nowDate: Date = Date()
let referenceDate: Date = Date().addingTimeInterval(20)
let calender = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
var timer: Timer {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) {_ in
        self.nowDate = Date()

        }

var body: some View {

    Text(countDownString(from: referenceDate, until: nowDate)).font(.largeTitle).onAppear(perform: {
                    _ = self.timer
                })

    }
    func countDownString(from date: Date, until nowDate: Date) -> String
{
  let components = calender.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: nowDate, to: date)



    return String(format: "%02dh:%02dm:%02ds",
                  components.hour ?? 00,
                  components.minute ?? 00,
                  components.second ?? 00)
}
```

Comment: *I hope someone could help me with my problem.* It would be better if you specify what exactly your problem is (specifically: what you expect and what you get from your current code).

Comment: Right now im getting a countdown timer which actually has the form "24:00:00". The problem is that the timer keeps running after being at "00:00:00" and starts counting down negative numbers. What i want is the timer to stop at 0 and repeat at 24 hours. My problem is that the time is of the Data.type Date(). so i don't know how to explain with an if statement that the textlabel  should change if the countdown timer == 0. I hope you understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var nowDate: Date = Date()
    let referenceDate: Date = Date().addingTimeInterval(20)
    let calender = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()


    var timer: Timer {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) {_ in
            self.nowDate = Date()

        }


    }
    func countDownString(from date: Date, until nowDate: Date) -> String
    {
        let components = calender.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: nowDate, to: date)

        return String(format: "%02dh:%02dm:%02ds",
                      components.hour ?? 00,
                      components.minute ?? 00,
                      components.second ?? 00)
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(countDownString(from: referenceDate, until: nowDate)).font(.largeTitle).onAppear(perform: {
            _ = self.timer
        })    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i cant see the different between this code and mine :/